# Check pacman movement

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am making pacman game but this is something that I don't know how to do:
When the pacman hits the food, the food should disappear. My code is not working. Here is the function for initializing the food world:

```
 namespace pacman
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Timer timer;
    Pacman pacman;
    static readonly int TIMER_INTERVAL = 250;
    static readonly int WORLD_WIDTH = 15;
    static readonly int WORLD_HEIGHT = 10;
    Image foodImage;
    bool[][] foodWorld;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        foodImage = Properties.Resources.foodImage;
        DoubleBuffered = true;
        newGame();
    }

    public void newGame()
    {
        pacman = new Pacman();
        this.Width = Pacman.radius * 2 * (WORLD_WIDTH + 1);
        this.Height = Pacman.radius * 2 * (WORLD_HEIGHT + 1);
         // овде кодот за иницијализација на матрицата foodWorld

        foodWorld = new bool[WORLD_WIDTH][];
        for (int i = 0; i < WORLD_WIDTH;i++ )
        {
            foodWorld[i] = new bool[WORLD_HEIGHT];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < WORLD_WIDTH; i+=2) {
            for (int j = 0; j < WORLD_HEIGHT; j++) {

                foodWorld[i][j] = true;

            }
        }

        // овде кодот за иницијализација и стартување на тајмерот
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = TIMER_INTERVAL;
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        timer.Start();
    }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // овде вашиот код
        timer.Interval = TIMER_INTERVAL - 1;
        if (TIMER_INTERVAL == 0)
        {
            timer.Stop();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < WORLD_WIDTH; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < WORLD_HEIGHT; j++) {

                if (pacman.x == i && pacman.y == j && foodWorld[i][j])
                {

                    foodWorld[i][j] = false;
                    this.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.Form1_Paint);
                    pacman.open = true;
                }
                else {

                    pacman.open = false;
                }
            }
        }

        pacman.Move(WORLD_WIDTH, WORLD_HEIGHT);
        Invalidate();
    }

    private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // не заборавајте да го додадете настанот на самата форма
        // вашиот код овде
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up) {

            pacman.ChangeDirection("UP");
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
        {

            pacman.ChangeDirection("DOWN");
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
        {

            pacman.ChangeDirection("LEFT");
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
        {

            pacman.ChangeDirection("RIGHT");
        }

        Invalidate();
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        g.Clear(Color.White);
        for (int i = 0; i < foodWorld.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < foodWorld[i].Length; j++)
            {
                if (foodWorld[i][j])
                {
                    g.DrawImageUnscaled(foodImage, j * Pacman.radius * 2 + (Pacman.radius * 2 - foodImage.Height) / 2, i * Pacman.radius * 2 + (Pacman.radius * 2 - foodImage.Width) / 2);
                }
            }
        }
        pacman.Draw(g);

    }

}
   }
```

What should I change so the picture that is touched by the pacman disappears?

Comment: you need to post the method(s) that the code in the first snippet belongs to.. also have you stepped through your own code so that you can try to pinpoint where your disconnect is happening..?

Comment: I posted everything I had on that page in the edit. And yes, I've been stuck on this for two hours now and have absolutely no idea where the mistake is.

Comment: Are you sure that the pacman's position is actually at the food's position when the timer ticks? Have you set a breakpoint on the line `foodWorld[i][j] = false` to make sure that the code is even being executed? I suspect that the flag is never being cleared.

Comment: I checked now and http://prntscr.com/70fvi6 this is where it never enters. The thing is this should work right? How am I supposed to check the position in a different way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When pacman eats the food, you have this:

```
this.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.Form1_Paint);
```

This syntax is a subscription to the Paint event. You should have done that once and only once. Instead, use:

```
this.Invalidate();
```

The call to Invalidate tell the operating system, "Hey, I need to be re-painted!". The operating system will then generate the event which ultimately triggers the Paint event and executes your paint code.

Comment: I changed it but nothing changed. The images are not disappearing.

Comment: @Spirit_Scarlet Probably because the timer stopped. You begin with a 1/4 second timer interval, then every time it fires, you shorten the interval by one. Without doing the math, I'd say that your timer stops in a few dozen seconds? Perform the food check when the pacman moves, rather than in a timer.